# Only one mouse at a time can move the cursor on my PC (Laptop accepts both at once). How could that be changed?

Tags: windows, mouse, hid

Only one mouse can control the cursor on my Windows 10 Desktop at a time.

**Example:**

```
1. Mouse A plugged in.
2. Mouse B plugged in.

-> Mouse A can move the cursor and interact with the PC.
-> Mouse B can not.

3. Mouse A unplugged.

-> Mouse B can now use the cursor.
```

Normally both mice would/should be able to move the cursor all the time, as they can on the laptop I tried it on.

I think it has to be something in Windows, like a setting or so but I don't know where that setting would be, how it could be named, and why it would be changed.

I have tried searching online for: *only one mouse works* | *only one mouse can move cursor* | *Only one mouse at a time can move cursor* | *...* and I have sadly found nothing about this problem.

So the question is: **How can I use both mice at the same time?** Like I can on the laptop.

---

And for anyone wondering why I need two mice, I am currently troubleshooting a different problem with my main mouse.

Comment: Is your laptop mouse the built in Track Point / Track Pad?  If so, then your laptop mouse operation is normal.  Two USB mice in a desktop does not work (for me).

Comment: @John I can simultaneously use both the built-in touchpad and the USB mouse on my laptop. Maybe you have the same issue than the original poster

Comment: So can I on my laptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of Valorant.

---

I tried it in Safe Mode and both mice worked, then I started Windows normally and both mice worked until I started Valorant, which I had running in the background before, as that was the game I was troubleshooting my other mouse problem for.

I should have tried a bit more troubleshooting steps before posting. Or maybe not, and this can help someone else in the future.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.